# Is there a term for "English that doesn't make sense"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, wasei-eigo

There are a lot of crazy combinations of English words and translations that don't make sense. Is there a specific term that identifies this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [和製英語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E) *wasei eigo* "Japanese English" for pseudo-English Made in Japan, e.g. アイスキャンディー *ice candy* "popsicle", etc.

Some relevant links

- [wasei-eigo](/questions/tagged/wasei-eigo) on Japanese.SE
- [和製英語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E) on Japanese Wikipedia
- [Wasei-eigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wasei-eigo) on English Wikipedia
- [List of wasei-eigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wasei-eigo) on English Wikipedia

There are also loanwords of Japanese origin (often hybrids from different languages):

- [和製外来語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%92%8C%E8%A3%BD%E5%A4%96%E6%9D%A5%E8%AA%9E)